# Tpl's Continuations and exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

If I have a task which throws an exception  , I can check in the continuation if there was an exception:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write (ant.Exception));
```

But I also know that :

> If an **antecedent** throws and the continuation **fails** to query the
>   antecedent’s Exception property (and the antecedent isn’t otherwise
>   waited upon), the exception is considered unhandled and the
>   **application dies** .

So I tried :

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write (1));//1
```

But the application didn't crash.

Please, What am I missing ?

Comment: Try adding a call to Task.Wait()

Comment: Try task2 (although task1 would throw too): `task2.Wait()`

Comment: but it says : _and the antecedent isn’t otherwise waited upon_.... and I'm not waiting for it , so it should crash...no?

Comment: BTW, `throw null` is a weird way to cause `NullReferenceException`. I believe the usual way to do something like this is `throw new Exception()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tend to disagree. I can read Task.result or wait and it will throw exception. till here we agree. but AFAIK if a child task throw an exception , and the father fails to query this exception , the application is down. nothing related to waiting.

Comment: I think it will only die if the finalizer for the task in question runs. Looks like it's not running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few different things going on:

First, if you call `Wait()` on a faulted `Task`, it will *always* throw an exception, no matter if you already observed it or not. In your code, this means that if you call `task.Wait()` from `Main()`, the whole application will crash, because you have unhandled exception in `Main()`.

Second, [the behavior of unhandled exceptions in `Task`s changed in .Net 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx) and they will no longer cause the application to crash. The article also describes how to switch back to the original behavior. And if you have .Net 4.5 installed, this applies also to applications targeting .Net 4.0 (e.g. those built using VS 2010).

Third, with the .net 4.0 behavior, the application crashes *when the `Task` is garbage collected* (assuming the exception wasn't observed before that point). This is because before that, there is still a chance your code will observe that exception.

So, the following code crashes the application (assuming you enabled the .Net 4.0 behavior if you have .Net 4.5 installed):

```
static void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });

    // give the Task some time to run
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    GC.Collect();
}
```

Your code didn't crash, because the GC didn't have chance to run before the application exited normally.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Like I said, it doesn't matter what compilation target are you using, what matters is which version you have installed. When you say “I'm on 4”, it's not clear what exactly do you mean.

Comment: Holly SHI* you are right.  it is becuase the GC. !!! I did this test :`Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write (ant.Exception==null?"0":"1"));
   Thread.Sleep(100);

 GC.Collect();
Console.ReadLine();` and it didnt go bang but when I remove the ?: checking , it went BANG

Comment: vs2010 fw 4. thats what  I meant.( I didnt mean compilation target )

Comment: Svick , is there a difference between my sample vs continueWith(...).continueWith(...)?   [at the exception pov]...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't understand what exactly do you mean. If `Task` with unobserved exception is GCed, the application will crash. There are various ways how you can observe the exception and various ways to keep the `Task` from being GCed, but that doesn't change the underlying principle.

Comment: Ill rephrase . Is there a difference between task2 which is continuing task1 vs a single task which has 2 continueWith  ? Thank you for your kind answers ( as always )

Comment: Ignore my last comment please. I asked a new question about it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322057/task-continuewith-vs-2-tasks)