# Task.ContinueWith() vs 2 Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

When should I use

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {...})
                 .ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write ("2"));
```

vs

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {... });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write ("2"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the same, except for you'll have a reference to the second task now. You can use the second option if the first task needs some processing before executing the tasks all together. An example is to add another `var task3 = task1.ContinueWith()` so task two and three will execute concurrently, but only if the first task is done processing. Actually it should be:

```
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {...}).ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write ("2"));

Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {... });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write ("2"));
```

Note I replaced `task1` to `task2`. Starting either Task will cause `task1` to start first.

Comment: So at your first sample , task2 will reference the last task executed ?

Comment: Exactly. I added another example where you might want to use both variables.

Comment: Note that you can also call Task.ContinueWith() multiple times for the same Task object (passing a different Task to continue with each time). This has the effect of starting the *ContinueWith* tasks all at once when the main task completed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you supply an example?